# How to get confirmations for incoming transactions?

Tags: confirmations

I'm currently working on accepting Bitcoins on my website. To do this I create a new address for every sale. I know I can get the amount of bitcoins that were paid into this address by using `./btcoind getreceivedbyaddress <the-address> 0` or `conn.getreceivedbyaddress(localAddress, 0)` when using the [python binding for bitcoin](https://github.com/laanwj/bitcoin-python). So far so good.

I now also want to get and display the amount of confirmations to the customer. So I made this:

```
highestConfirmCount = None
for i in count():
    received = btcConn.getreceivedbyaddress(localAddress, i)
    if received >= amountExpected:
        highestConfirmCount = i
    else:
        break
print highestConfirmCount
```

This works fine, but it's pretty slow for incoming payments which have been a while ago. Also, I would presume there would be a better and more efficient built in function for this, but I can't find anything like it.

Does anybody know what the best way is for getting confirmations for incoming payments to a specific address?

Answer (score 2):

Calling `bitcoin-cli listunspent 0 9999999 "[\"someLocalAddress\",\"someOtherLocalAddress\"]"` will provide you with the exact number of confirmations for every transaction to these addresses so you will not need to perform all these iterations.

Replacing `9999999` with what you consider in your application to be a confirmed transaction will only return the unconfirmed transactions, which is more effective if you already keep track of the confirmed transactions in your database.